# Add a "Like" button after "Edit" and "Reply" links

Tags: theming, flags

How can I [add a *Like* link using the Flag Module](https://drupal.org/node/295383), exactly after the *Edit* and the *Reply* links?

[image: screenshot]

I know I must use `print flag_create_link('bookmarks', $node->nid);`, but I don't know exactly where to place it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implement [`hook_node_view()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_view/7) in a custom module that you create.

```
$node->content['links'][] = array(
  '#markup' => flag_create_link('bookmarks', $node->nid),
);
```

Or use the function `MY_THEME_preprocess_node()` in your template.php and add:

```
function MY_THEME_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
  $node = $variables['node'];
  $variables['content']['links'][] = flag_create_link('bookmarks', $node->nid);
}
```

Replace MY_THEME with the name of your theme.
Some reading that might help you: http://www.whenwhowhere.com/tech-blog/add-variable-theme-template-files-drupal-7

Comment: @user25329: I have update the answer to show how you could do it in a preprocess function.

Comment: @user25329 Themes and modules can implement alter hooks like `hook_node_view_alter()`; only modules can implement the other hooks like `hook_node_view()`.